# System.Reflection.TargetException on employee.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name)

Tags: c#, system.reflection

<s>I have come upon an issue I can't seem to figure out. I'm sure there's a simple explanation to this, but I don't understand why I get a System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type' when I try to get a property from (in this case) the employee object.</s>

```
employee.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name)
```

Searching for the error returns many results describing problems with calling the Set/GetValue methods, but I haven't found a solution to this one.

I've set a breakpoint where the exception is thrown and it shows that property.Name is indeed a value - and a real property of the object. I've also tried manually specifying a property I know exists. Still the same.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Tried the following instead:

```
Type type = typeof (Employee); //Throws the TargetException
PropertyInfo theProperty = type.GetProperty(property.Name);
```

And now the same exception is thrown at the first line above instead.

EDIT: Added code and more details about the application I'm building.

Class definition for Employee (to simplify mapping to the JSON data this class "represents", the class/fields are in Norwegian - which is the format/language the data comes in, sorry :-).)

"Ansatt" = Employee. "Ansattnummer" = EmployeeNo.

```
[JsonObject]
public class Ansatt
{
    public int Ansattnummer { get; set; }
    public string Fornavn { get; set; }
    public string Etternavn { get; set; }
    public int Pin { get; set; }
    public string Adresse { get; set; }
    public int Postnummer { get; set; }
    public string Poststed { get; set; }
    public int TlfPrivat { get; set; }
    public int MobilTlf { get; set; }
    public string EpostAdresse { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fodt { get; set; }
}
```

My application retrieves a given dataset from a web service - it could be employees, projects or a few other possible datasets. What data to fetch is determined at runtime - by the user. The user can also specify via URL-query which portions, e.g. columns, of the dataset he/she wants. The program then creates a csv-file with the selected data.

Here's the code I use for this:

```
 if (records != null && records.Count != 0) //records contains the chosen dataset - in this case Employees (Ansatt).
                {
                    if (records.GetType() == typeof (List<Ansatt>))
                    {
                        foreach (var model in records as List<Ansatt>)
                        {
                            var temp = new Ansatt();

                            foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
                            {

                                var currentProperty = model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);

                                if (currentProperty != null)
                                {
                                    Type type = typeof (Ansatt); //Throws System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type'
                                    PropertyInfo tempProperty = type.GetProperty(property.Name);
                                    tempProperty.SetValue(temp, currentProperty.GetValue(property.Name));
                                }
                            }

                            csv.WriteRecord(temp);

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: What is `property.Name`?

Comment: property.Name is int32 EmployeeNo

Comment: .GetProperty() takes the name of the property as a String, not int32.

Comment: yeah, sorry. property.Name returns "EmployeeNo" - so I do supply GetProperty() with a string. Value of "EmployeeNo" is an int

Comment: Show us more info about the exception(StackTace,InnerException)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx) goes, you should use it this way:

```
class MyClass {
    private int myProperty;
    // Declare MyProperty. 
    public int MyProperty {
        get {
            return myProperty;
        }
        set {
            myProperty = value;
        }
    }
}

public class MyTypeClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            // Get the Type object corresponding to MyClass.
            Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
            // Get the PropertyInfo object by passing the property name.
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty("MyProperty");
            // Display the property name.
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} property exists in MyClass.", myPropInfo.Name);

            // Instantiate MyClass
            var myObject = new MyClass()
            {
                MyProperty = 5
            };

            // Get value using reflection
            Console.WriteLine("My property value for my object is {0}.", myPropInfo.GetValue(myObject));

        } catch (NullReferenceException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("The property does not exist in MyClass." + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

For your code, when you want to get the property value of an object instance, you should pass object as reference to PropertyInfo.GetValue(object) function.
Instead of this:

```
tempProperty.SetValue(temp, currentProperty.GetValue(property.Name));
```

Do this:

```
tempProperty.SetValue(temp, currentProperty.GetValue(model));
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way, and now the exception is thrown when I call
'Type type = typeof (Employee);

Comment: Post your code for Employee class definition please.

Comment: Kerem: Updated the question with more details

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the name of the property

```cs
PropertyInfo value = employee.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

For you to get the property of object through reflection, make it sure that the property name is public with getter and setter else it will return null.

Ex.

```
public class Employee
{
   public string YouProperty { get; set; }
}

var employee = new Employee();

var result = employee.GetType().GetProperty("YouProperty");

// The result is property info
```

Kindly read some information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a public getter and setter on the property.

Comment: Does your property.Name match to the property you want to get?

Comment: Could you post the code of your employee and your property.Name? It seems to be weird just for a simple reflection.